# Domain Transfer - Years locked in?

Tags: domain-transfer

Wondered if anyone could help? I transferred a domain name (.co.uk) for a customer over to Enom. All went well, no issue. Now its renewal time, they state that they brought 2 years on the domain name (they brought in May, I transfered in August) however all records on enom and whois is showing renewal to be May 2019. I was under the impression renewal dates are locked and would carry over in the transfer. Am i wrong or is the customer mistaken?

Comment: What do you mean when you say they "brought 2 years on the domain in May"? Do you mean that they *bought* 2 years, or that they brought the domain to you from elsewhere, with 2 years on the registration?

Answer (score 2):

> I was under the impression renewal dates are locked and would carry over in the transfer

This is indeed the case for .UK which is an exception as in almost all other TLDs a transfer will add one year to the expiration date.

Unfortunately the registry whois output does not show expiration dates.

The registrar should be the point of contact for you/the client to sort the issue. Or at the last resort the registry itself.

You need to discover what was the expiration date before the transfer.

It had happened in the past that some registrars were not applying multi-years immediately: you ask to buy a domain for 5 years, they will register it at registry for 1 and then each year during 4 years renew it for one year. It theoretically does not change the outcome except for two points:

1. they profit from the money during the time they do not use it to renew it (instead of giving immediately it for the 5 years at the registry)
2. the registry knows only what the registrar did not what the registrar got from the client, hence the expiration date will be only one year in the future, which will be a problem if a transfer takes place as the missing years will never happen.

I do not know if you are in that case but you need to understand what was the expiration date before the transfer and the new registrar should be able to help you with that.

If your client bought the domain in May 2018 for 2 years, and you transferred in August 2018 and now the new registrar says it expires in May 2019 then:

- either the client did only 1 year registration not 2 (it should probably have an invoice for its registration, so it should be written there 1 or 2 years)
- or the client paid for 2 but the previous registrar registered for 1 year and was waiting for May 2019 to renew it for one more year, but since you transferred it in August 2018, the renewal by old registrar on May 2019 will never happen
- or the current registrar wants to make you to pay for the year (did you read its contract to see what happens in cases like this?), because technically even if you paid the previous registrar for 2 years (maybe) you are now using the new registrar systems to maintain your domain so it can make you pay for this (again, this should be all spelled out clearly in the contract you agreed with when you transferred)

No one here will be able to tell you in which case you are...
(but I did put the options in the order starting with what could be more probable...)